# I can't download sitecore 8.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.1

Is there any license required to download sitecore from the official site.
I searched a lot on https://dev.sitecore.net/. but can't find.
Message Prompts."That are you sitecore certified."I am not..so whats the solution or is there any other link available. Thanks all!

Comment: Contact Sitecore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Sitecore certified peoples can download Sitecore on dev.sitecore.net. And you need a valid license file to run Sitecore. Sitecore doesn't provide a trial version. Contact with your Sitecore regional office, or with a Sitecore partner.

Comment: If you are associated with a Sitecore Partner you have access through that association as well. You need to make a profile on https://profile.sitecore.net/en/SignUp/Signup.aspx then contact Sitecore to become associated a Sitecore Partner if applicable.